# MVC для игры морской бой

Tags: c++, mvc, проектирование

Разделил логику от интерфейса на составляющие MVC

**Model:**

Класс Game в котором реализованы игроки, у каждого игрока есть поле, корабли и так далее

**View:**

2 объекта класса TField (визуальный компонент)

**Controller:**

Класс GameController, который должен связывать логику игры и ходы с визуальным представлением на форме.

Именно на контроллере стал задумываться, как связать их. Определить в классе GameController объекты классов модели и визуального представления? Но как их связать? Обработку нажатия на клетку в поле, отправку координат X и Y в класс Game и обратно получить ответ, обработав попадание/не попадание?

Я частично понял, как реализовать все это. У нас есть цепочка:

> Представление -> Контроллер -> Модель

Представление вызывает клик и отправляет контроллеру событие о выстреле. Контроллер передает информацию об это модели на обработку. Но как сделать обновление Представления после изменений в Модели я так и не понял.

Я так понимаю, что нужно создать слушателя/-ей, которые будут вызываться из Модели при обновлении данных. Но это значит, что Модель должна содержать ссылку на Представление, что по сути перечит MVC, если Модель должна не знать о Представлении. Есть мысли?

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Если его скинуть весь, то это будет одна большая непонятная кракозябра :)

Comment: Для меня главное понять, как при обработке событий в представлении передать все это контроллеру, затем передать модели, а модель, изменив своё состояние, передаст это представлению для визуальных изменений.

Comment: паттерн mvc как правило юзается для веба, по этому хочу уточнить, вы пишете веб солюшен, или обычный апп?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов Десктоп приложение, но с взаимодействием по сети.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов вы не совсем правы, MVC - это еще и парадигма, включающая одноименный паттерн и не менее одноименный фреймворк от MS и много чего еще. Суть всех MV* паттернов сводится к разделению модели и ее представления, а также обеспечения прослойки позволяющей им взаимодействовать.

Comment: @rdorn  Вы не согласны с тем, что mvc чаще юзается для веба и реже для обычных приложений?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов как паттерн, да в основном для веба в силу особенностей этого самого веба.

Comment: @rdorn вот по этому я и уточнял вопрос, по тому, что при наличии большого желания можно плюсы использовать и для веба :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите. Вам нужен по идее `event` или `Listener`, или как там этот паттерн называется.

Суть такова.

Модель выставляет метод `Subscribe()`, в который можно передать `callback`, который будет вызван при изменении свойства. Представление знает о модели, и подписывается на её изменения. Таким образом, модель ничего не знает о представлении, но может дёрнуть это самое представление, когда что-то поменялось.

Пример на коленке:

```
class Model
{
public:
    typedef int Token;

    Token subscribe(std::function<void(void)> callback)
    {
        max_token++;
        callbacks[max_token] = callback;
        return max_token;
    }

    void unsubscribe(Token token)
    {
        callbacks.erase(token);
    }

private:
    std::map<Token, std::function<void()>> callbacks;
    Token max_token = -1;

    // это дёрнет все callback'и
    void notifyall()
    {
        for (auto& kv : callbacks)
            kv.second();
    }
};
```

```
class View
{
    Model* model;
    Model::Token token;

    //...
    View(Model* model) : model(model)
    {
        token = model->subscribe([this] { OnModelUpdate(); });
    }

    ~View()
    {
        model->unsubscribe(token);
    }
};
```

Comment: А ведь можно попроще как-нибудь? Сделать к примеру класс с виртуальной функцией Update(Model& m), наследовать от него все View, если их несколько и добавить в Модель лист с этими объектами. А потом вызвать NotifyAll и перебрав лист, вызвать Update у всех View

Comment: @T2skler: Ну, раньше так и приходилось делать. Но представьте себе, что у вас view хочет подписываться на несколько разных моделей. Или скажем ещё на что-то, что тоже требует виртуальную функцию `Update`. Подписывание произвольной функции удобнее.

Comment: Можно ещё один вопрос? Контроллер должен порождать Представление или Представление Контроллер?

Comment: @T2skler: Не знаю, честно говоря, и думаю, что в каждом паттерне по-своему. В MVVM, например, в идеальном случае контроллер (view model) должен порождать представление, но т. к. обычно проще просто открыть окно, то многие делают наоборот.

Comment: Но тогда встает вопрос в последнем случае, когда Контроллер пораждает Модель: как Модель будет при каком-либо событии возвращать данные Контроллеру?

Comment: Ну, поскольку контроллер инициирует изменения модели, он может сам перечитать по идее. Ну и в MVC вроде бы контроллеру вовсе не нужны данные из модели, если я правильно помню, он просто пинает её, а данные перечитывает представление, а не контроллер.

Comment: Ошибся. Вместо Модели я имел ввиду Представление. Когда Контроллер пораждает Представление: как Представление будет при каком-либо событии возвращать данные Контроллеру? Вот так правильно

Comment: @T2skler: Ну, пусть передаёт указатель/ссылку на себя, например.